# Does an iCloud restore on iPhone overwrite iTunes contacts/calendar etc?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud

If I sync my iPhone contacts, notes, calendar etc with iTunes and then restore my phone using iCloud, then sync again, will my iTunes contacts be overwritten by the restored version? Will my iPhone contacts have the iCloud version of my contacts, the iTunes version or some merge?

Comment: What is the iTunes version of your contacts (where are they stored)?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes doesn't sync Calendar & Contacts unless iCloud [over-the-air] sync is off, so there is nothing to merge.

[image]
[image]